# spring data cassandra default limit 10

Tags: java, solr, cassandra

I use spring-data-cassandra to query data from cassandra. I use the way of solr query like this;

```
select * 
from m_sitearticle_item 
where solr_query='matnr:*123*'
```

Finally, I just get 10 results, but actually there are 100 results. Now I change the solrconfig.xml, but it doesn't work. Is there some problems about it?

Comment: What exactly did you change in solrconfig.xml?

Comment: <requestHandler class="com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.handler.component.CqlSearchHandler" name="solr_query">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <int name="rows">10000</int>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>                I add the config like this

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by changing this setting in `/etc/dse/dse.yaml`:

```
cql_solr_query_paging: driver
```

Another way is to set a high number for `LIMIT` in the query.

See 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/config/configDseYaml.html#configDseYaml__CQLSolrPaging